# Firefox: How can I add/modify toolbars using the firefox extension

Tags: firefox, toolbar, firefox-addon-webextensions

How to add button in toolbar of print preview fire fox using firefox extension. I can't find the post: [Firefox: How can I add/modify toolbars using the Add-on SDK (Jetpack)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572632/firefox-how-can-i-add-modify-toolbars-using-the-add-on-sdk-jetpack) and 
[How to add button in toolbar of print preview fire fox using add SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238913/how-to-add-button-in-toolbar-of-print-preview-fire-fox-using-add-sdk)
It no longer works on new firefox versions.
[image]

Thank you so much

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: I have been able to do it on firefox 39 version but recent versions do not support the old libraries :(

Comment: Since Firefox 57, extensions no longer allowed to modify toolbar.